# Gradle sync failed: CreateProcess failed, error=216 Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When android studio starts, it cannot sync with gradle.

The error message is:
Gradle sync failed: CreateProcess failed, error=216
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

I cannot find an answer anywhere! The only solutions I found are for the message:
“Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you’re running” which is not the case. I tried everything I found even for this message but nothing works.

Also, I tried older verision of android studio and gradle and still nothing.

My computer runs windows 7, 32bit

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution!

It was one more error, that was shown only in the beggining that I overlooked it:

filenotfoundexception: entry filetemplates//code/google test fixture setup method.cc.ft not found in c:/program files/android/android studio/lib/idea.jar

I found the answer for fixing it here:
http://fxcode121.blogspot.com/2015/07/filenotfoundexception-exception-in.html